# Draw a line if value of signal is bigger than mean of the signal

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib, signal-processing

I want to draw a line on a graph when the value of my signal will be greater than the mean value of this signal. My signal is simple concatenation of muscle pulling and relaxing.

```
muscle_on2 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1000) + offs
muscle_off = np.random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05, 500) + offs
emg = np.concatenate([muscle_off, muscle_on1, muscle_off, muscle_on2, muscle_off])
```

In order to do this I tried something like this:

```
pl.plot(x_axis)
for i in range(0, len(emg), 1):
    if emg[i]>RM:
        pl.plot([i, 1.0], [i, 1.0], 'r-', lw=5)
```

where RM is:

```
RM = np.mean(emg)
```

however, instead of producing horizontal line, it produces vertical line: 
[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

I forgot to clarify this, in this case offs (offset is already filtered out) this part of code was implemented to show how my signal is created. When I printed out the mean value of what's on the photo it oscillated around 0.26. I want my line to appear when the value of signal is bigger than the mean value and to end when the value of a signal is smaller than mean value.

Comment: what is `offs` in your code? Please provide a [mcve]. Also it's not clear how you want your line to be? horizontal? What would be the extension of the line?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to clarify it, in this case offs (offset is already filtered out) this part of code was implemented to show how my signal is created. When I printed out the mean value of what's on the photo it oscillated around 0.26. I want my line to appear when the value of signal is bigger than the mean value and to end when the value of a signal is smaller than mean value.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? Does that approach give you the output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either [`matplotlib.pyplot.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html),

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

muscle_on2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
muscle_off = np.random.uniform(0, 0.05, 500)
emg = np.concatenate([muscle_off, muscle_on2, muscle_off])
RM = np.mean(emg)
plt.plot(emg)
plt.axhline(RM, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Which will give you

[image]

or [`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) if you don't want to go all the way across the plot,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

muscle_on2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
muscle_off = np.random.uniform(0, 0.05, 500)
emg = np.concatenate([muscle_off, muscle_on2, muscle_off])
e = x[emg > RM]
plt.plot(x, emg)
plt.hlines(RM, e[0], e[-1], color='r', lw=2, zorder=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**Note**   -   The `import` convention for `matplotlib.pyplot` is

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and the convention for the [deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) `pylab` is

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
```

If you are using `pylab` then you should switch to `pyplot` as the [official usage guide](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related) indicates.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I guess it can be easily vectorized. I'll put something together when I have time if you haven't by then.

Comment: @anishtain4 Yeah, there is a much simpler way to filter: `x[emg > RM]` - I should have used it in the first place

Comment: Gotta use a combination of that and `np.diff` to find the start and end of the lines, then can use `plt.hlines` to draw all of them at once.

Comment: @anishtain4 If you want multiple regions where the moving average of the data exceeds the mean. I have neglected that for simplicity, if OP disambiguates *appear when the value of signal is bigger than the mean value and to end when the value of a signal is smaller than mean value* I will modify my answer accordingly